# When sign in with google plus getting an error '10'

Tags: ionic-framework, google-plus-signin

When I sign in with google. I am getting the popup of gmail list but when I select any gmail. I get an error as 10.

**.ts file**

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx'; 

    loginWithGP(){

       this.googlePlus.login({
          'webClientId': '#####', //reverse client id
          'offline': true
        }).then(res=>{
          console.log('res', res)
          this.userInfo=res;
          this.isUserLoggedIn=true;
          }).catch( err => console.log(err ,'error'));
    }
```

**.html file**

```
    <ion-card *ngIf="isUserLoggedIn" style="text-align:center">
      <img [src]="userInfo.imageUrl" />
      <h3>{{userInfo.displayName}}</h3>
      <p>{{userInfo.email}}</p>
      <ion-button ion-button clear (click)="logout()">Logout</ion-button>
    </ion-card>

    <ion-footer *ngIf="!isUserLoggedIn">
      <ion-button ion-button block (click)="loginWithGP()">Login with Google+</ion-button>
    </ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its occurred mismatch about your SHA-1 key  mismatch with app id or your release or debug key

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=279073034910-0000000000000000000.apps.googleusercontent.com

npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus@4
```

[image]

**Note:** in ionic youcan find `packagename` config.xml top of it `widget id="com.your.id"`

Comment: i tried again but facing the same issue.....can you guide me step by step

Comment: first do you have keystore?

Comment: do you add othclient id

Comment: so is it same sha-1 that do you have keystore file or are you dev without keystore

Comment: generated SHA1 with the help of this link    https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197871/discussion-between-annaya-and-orbit).

Comment: is that the reversed client id should be in the reverse format (com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxxxx)